# Google Places API Error, but returns success

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api, google-places

I was working with the google places autocomplete api when I noticed certain address would return error while others worked perfectly. Even on error however, the error callback would show the error message had an `error code : 0` and status of `Success`. I'm using the google places autocomplete `Fragment`.

The error printed out : `I/DESTINATION: An error occurred: SUCCESS`

```
private void setDestinationAutocompleteCallbacks() {
    DestinationautocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
      @Override
      public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        LatLng destinationLatLng = place.getLatLng();
        OriginAndDestinationLocations[1] = destinationLatLng;

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(destinationLatLng)
            .title(getString(R.string.destinationLocation))
            .snippet(place.getAddress().toString()))
            .showInfoWindow();

        if (OriginAndDestinationLocations[0] != null) {
          adjustZoom();
        } else {
          mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(destinationLatLng, Zoom), 2000, null);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Status status) {
        Log.i(DESTINATIONTAG, "An error occurred: " + status.getStatusMessage());
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

You may be use same google api key for more than one Application in android. so remove the google api key from other application.
   Another way is generate new api key for current application.